# Win8 navigation feature like navigation Drawer in Android

Tags: user-interface, windows-8, microsoft-metro, user-experience

I have a hierarchy in form of

1. Type 1

   - Subtype 1
   - Subtype 2
2. Type 2

   - Subtype 1
   - Subtype 2
3. Type n

   - Subtype n

Now in android i would have used Navigation Drawer and implemented it .In Windows 8 i know navigation in Appbars but it wont work here.[Image For Reference](http://tctechcrunch2011.files.wordpress.com/2013/05/google_nav_drawer.jpg)

I need user to reach subtype within 2 CLicks.

Is there any sdebar feature in Win 8 which i can implement in the app?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Accordion control.

[image]

Check out this [Silverlight port of that control](https://github.com/brendankowitz/ZeroProximity.Accordion)